# remember radio option after submission error

Tags: javascript, html

I have a contact form created with formtools with several radio buttons. I need to make the form remember the option on the selected radio button, even though there is a error in the post submission.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('submit');
  if (btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var dt = document.querySelector('[name="form_tools_form_id"]:checked').value;
        alert('&option=' + dt)
    });
  }
```

```html
<form action="check.php" id="contact" method="post">
  <div class="radioboxes"><strong id="top-more">Options</strong><br>
  <span class="othertopic" id="wwus"> <font>Please select one option</font></span>
  <div id="top-wwus"><input id="topic_252" name="form_tools_form_id" type="radio" value="252"> <label for="topic_252">Recruitment</label><br>
  <input id="topic_259" name="form_tools_form_id" type="radio" value="259"> <label for="topic_259">Requests</label><br>
  <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button> </div> </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: font tags are obsolete and should not be used.  You could try using local storage if this has to be with js, probably better than cookies as it won't persist.  But I would say this type of stuff is probably better done server side

Comment: Both cookie and localStorage could be your answer.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font notice the red box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't gave your submit button the id submit which you were using in your event listener and you have to use `.preventDefault()` so that it alerts otherwise it will only redirect. Store the value in localStorage

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('submit');
  if (btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log(dt)
    e.preventDefault();
        var dt = document.querySelector('[name="form_tools_form_id"]:checked').value;
        alert('&option=' + dt)
localStorage.setItem('radio',dt);
    });
  }
```

```html
<form action="check.php" id="contact" method="post">
  <div class="radioboxes"><strong id="top-more">Options</strong><br>
  <span class="othertopic" id="wwus"> <font>Please select one option</font></span>
  <div id="top-wwus"><input id="topic_252" name="form_tools_form_id" type="radio" value="252"> <label for="topic_252">Recruitment</label><br>
  <input id="topic_259" name="form_tools_form_id" type="radio" value="259"> <label for="topic_259">Requests</label><br>
  <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button> </div> </div> 
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you reload the page then use cookies or session/locale storage

```
document.cookie = "value = " + document.querySelector('[name="form_tools_form_id"]:checked').value + ";";
```

when the page reload, check if it is empty or not

```
var x = document.cookie;
```

then check the checkbox

```
document.querySelector('[name="form_tools_form_id"]:checked').checked = true;
```

Comment: But, if you can, use ajax, is easy to send and to receive answers to/from server

Comment: please put 4 space in front of your code to get a good answer layout